# Oneup flysystem and liip imagine local cache settigns

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle, flysystem

I have a folder outside the project root which contains uploaded images now i want to store the Liip imagine cache there as wel by making use of the oneup flysystem.

config.yml

```
liip_imagine:
    resolver:
        upload_adapter:
            flysystem:
                filesystem_service: oneup_flysystem.profile_photos_filesystem
                root_url:           "http://images.example.com"
                cache_prefix:       media/cache
                visibility:         public

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        thumb:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
        large:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [800, 600], mode: outbound }
    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                data_root: "%upload_file_path%"

oneup_flysystem:
    adapters:
        upload_adapter:
            local:
                directory: "%upload_file_path%"

    filesystems:
        deliva_filesystem:
            adapter: upload_adapter
```

But it keeps giving me this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked though the config of the bundle seems to be a breaking change, updating to 1.3 fixes the problem.